I can't add user to the Administrators group
Access is denied occurs if I want to add a user to the Administrators group.
If I allow Outbound connections for Domain Profile, adding the user works.
What firewall rule do I need, what port to open, please?


Another strange thing,
If I turn off the VM with the domain controller and also the next VM in the same domain.
and after starting the VMs, the Network Location type will change.
From Domain to Network Private.


I know that there is a problem with FireWall rules, but how do I find out which is wrong or what is missing?

Just to make sure I understand what you're saying: when you DISABLE Outbound connections for the Domain Profile in your Windows Firewall, you are unable to add users to the Administrator group. But when you ENABLE Outbound connections for the Domain Profile in the Windows firewall you are able to add users to the local administrator group? Is this computer on a domain, or is it a personal or lab computer? Why are you blocking Outbound connections on the Domain profile?

Why are you blocking any outbound connections? How do you expect to do domain operations if your computer can't connect to the domain?

It is a computer in the domain, it is a lab.
We have had to block all inbound and outbound traffic.
Then customize InBound and OutBound rules as required for your specific needs.
This is a requirement of our IT department to secure the VM environments.

Your computer needs to communicate with the domain controllers. Blocking ALL/ANY Outbound connections prevents it from doing this. This is the main reason you are having this problem. Outbound connections inside a Domain are rarely an issue, and if there IS a problem, the Inbound rules on the system it is trying to connect to would help mitigate these as well as security software on the device itself. You should go back to your IT organization and discuss this security requirement with them. Either you misunderstand their rules, or they will need to rethink their rules.

Because this issue is with a business computer environment, it is not really on topic for this site. Your IT team needs to fix this for you.
